# Passing an input through JQuery attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, linkedin-api

I have a value that my site grabs from LinkedIn. I want to pass this value as an attribute for a script I run. My code is incorrect as it was just a shot in the dark at a solution. Any suggestions on how to make this functional?

```
<input type="hidden" name="linkedin-id"  value="<?js= id ?>" id = "person"/>
    <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#test" ).attr({
          'data-ids': $("#person").val(),
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: What's wrong with it, and why doesn't it work ?

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught Error: ids must be set either through the constructor or through .ids()

Comment: Doesn't sound like a javascript error, but a server error.

Comment: Your [subsequent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850303/javascript-uncaught-error) appears to ask this again, but that one notes the error in the question, so I'll vote to close this. I'd say there was no need in this case to ask another question - just an edit to the existing one would have been fine.

Answer (score 0):

can't see anything wrong in your code have u made sure to import the jquery library etc

```
<input type="hidden" name="linkedin-id"  value="<?js= id ?>" id = "person"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#test" ).attr({
          'data-ids': $("#person").val(),
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: just offering a suggestion dont see u helping

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught Error: ids must be set either through the constructor or through .ids()